# prove that a continuous function on the unit circle converge to $\int_0^1 f(e^{2 \pi i x})e^{-2 \pi i nx} dx$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a function on the circle. For each $N \geq 1$ the discrete Fourier
coefficients of $f$ are defined by $$a_N(n)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nf(e^{2 \pi i k/N})e^{-2 \pi i kn/N}\ \ \ \text{for}\ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
we also let $$a_n=\int_0^1 f(e^{2 \pi i x})e^{-2 \pi i nx} dx$$
denotes the ordinary Fourier coefficients of $f$. Show that
if $f$ is continuous on the circle, then $a_N(n)\rightarrow a_n$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on the circle, and hence it is bounded since the circle is compact.

But how to guarantee that $f(e^{2 \pi i k/N})$ is bounded as well?

I would appreciate any help with this

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $g_n(x)=f(e^{2i\pi nx})e^{-2i\pi nx}$ is continuous, so it is Riemann-integrable. Now notice that $a_N(n)$ is a Riemann sum.

Comment: Could you please help me more??

Comment: Are you familiar with Riemann sums and their convergence towards integrals?

Comment: So the converges here is uniformlly !?

Comment: I'd recommend you read about Riemann sums on Google. I don't have any specifics sites to recommend, maybe start with Wikipedia?